# How to correctly handle functions in the translation files? (PHP templates)

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I've searched for this in the manual but I found nothing. 
I have for example this view:

```
//view.html.php
<?php $view->extend('::base.html.php') ?>
<?php $view['slots']->start('real-content') ?>

<?php echo $view['translator']->trans('user.name') ?>

<?php $view['slots']->stop('real-content') ?>
```

How can I insert the function `getUsername()` in the translation file in order to be rendered correctly?
Is this the best way?

```
//messages.en.php
'user.name' => 'Name: %user->getUsername()%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate the translation of `user.name` (the "label") and the actual call to the function returning the name value:

<kbd>view.html.php</kbd>

```
<?php $view->extend('::base.html.php') ?>
<?php $view['slots']->start('real-content') ?>

<?php echo $view['translator']->trans('user.name') . $user->getName(); ?>

<?php $view['slots']->stop('real-content') ?>
```

<kbd>messages.en.php</kbd>

```
'user.name' => 'Name: '
```

Answer (score 0):

trans function, when it finds a matching key, returns a value corresponding to the key.

Example

```
//message.tr.php
'username' => 'Kullanıcı adı'

//message.en.php
'username' => 'User name'
```

Uses

```
<?php echo $view['translator']->trans('username') ?>
```

Output

```
Kullanıcı adı
```

purpose for static text